# Async function doesn't pop off a second time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, ffmpeg, async-await

I'm creating a button to record a canvas using FFMPEG. Here's the code that finalizes the download process.

```
const recordButton = document.querySelector("#record")
recordButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
function startRecording() {
const { createFFmpeg } = FFmpeg;
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
  log: true
});

var transcode = async (webcamData) => {
  var name = `record${id}.webm`;
  await ffmpeg.load();
  await ffmpeg.write(name, webcamData);
  await ffmpeg.transcode(name, `output${id}.mp4`);
  var data = ffmpeg.read(`output${id}.mp4`);

  var video = document.getElementById('output-video');
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
  dl.href = video.src;
}

fn().then(async ({ url, blob }) => {
  transcode(new Uint8Array(await (blob).arrayBuffer()));
})

...

id += 1}
```

The problem arises with the **transcode** variable. While the button works initially, every other attempt (on a single page load) fails just the async function. I'm not well versed enough in the function to know why it would only work once. That said, I do know it is the only bit of code that does not fire off upon second attempt.

It could be a few things. This is borrowed code, and I've repurposed it for multiple uses. I may have messed up the declarations. It may be an async issue. I tried to use available values to rig up a secondary, similar function, but that would defeat the purpose of the first.

I tried clearing and appending the DOM elements affected, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Fails the`async` function means, can you post the error?

Comment: Reduce this code: for the purposes of this question, 90% of the code shown here is basically irrelevant (and as a bonus, the exercise of forming a [mcve] almost always let you go "oh hang on, is it..." and come out either with more precise details, or, more often than not, the solution without actually needing SO's help anymore)

Comment: @Navitas28 The FFMPEG library automatically logs the conversion process. The first iteration ends in "[ffmpeg-stdout] FFMPEG_END" and "[info] FS.readFile output2.mp4" while the second iteration only ends with "[ffmpeg-stdout] FFMPEG_END", undercutting the readFile output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with:

```
await ffmpeg.load();
```

While FFMPEG has to download and load the library initially, it does not have to do so the second initialization. That my be the trigger that is not activating with successive uses.